# How to find bitrate / resolution of youtube video in android ? Are there any APIs?

Tags: android, video, youtube

I am trying to get the resolution / bit rate of youtube videos . How can do it on Android ? Is there any client available ? Are there any APIs I can use ?

Comment: Did you do any research?

Comment: I don't know anything about Youtube videos, but presumably that information is available in the manifest file

Comment: @allcaps Is there a way to achieve this now on the YouTube Android app?